# Definite integral inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals

Let $f:[a,b] \to R$ be a differentiable function so that $f(b)=0$.Prove that there is a $c \in (a,b)$ which satisfies:
$$ f'(c) \int_a^c f(t) dt + c \ge \frac{a+b}{2} $$

Any useful ideas that can lead to a solution ? I'm really stuck here, I can't even find a decent starting point.

Comment: if $f'$ has a zero at z in $(\frac{a+b}2,b)$ then the inequality is satisfied for $c=z$, so you may assume the contrary

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but my first thought would be to try integration by parts on $f^{\prime}(c)\int_{a}^{c}f(t)dt$ and hope I can get somewhere using a Cauchy-Schwarz type inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=1-x,$ $a=0$ and $b=1.$ It is

$$f'(c)\int_0^c f(t)dt+c=-\int_0^c(1-t)dt+c=-c+\frac{c^2}{2}+c=\frac{c^2}{2}<\frac{1}{2}=\frac{a+b}{2}$$ for any $c\in (0,1).$

Comment: Uh, isn't this a bit too particular ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well we're supposed to prove that for any differentiable function defined on $[a,b]$ such that $f(b)=0$ there's a $c, a<c<b$ so that the inequality holds. You set your own function and values for $a,b$..How is this a solution to my question ?

Comment: It is a counterexample. The given inequality doesn't hold for any function satisfying the hypothesis you wrote.

Comment: terribly sorry, it's 3:30 AM here so I'm kinda fuzzy. I thought you merely gave an example of a function that satisfied my inequality. +1